# Gerar arquivo .ret Boleto

Tags: php

Pesquisei na internet e vi que o arquivo **.ret** serve para ver se o boleto foi pago.

Ja consegui abrir esse arquivo **.ret** com o **PHP** com alguns exemplos na internet, como faço para que o **PHP** gere esse arquivo **.ret** quando é gerado o boleto, afim de checar posteriormente se o mesmo foi pago?

Estou usando o boleto do Santander (se isso for relevante)

Comment: Consegui te ajudar? :)

Comment: Me ajudou sim amigo, queria ver uma forma de o site pegar esses arquivo .ret automático sem tem que estar acessando o site do Santander. Será que existe alguma forma? Porque como o PagSeguro faz por exemplo para saber se o boleto foi pago? Deve ser automático isso

Comment: Infelizmente isto só é possível através de VAN's (serviços terceirizados contratados)

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser entender um pouco mais sobre os arquivos .RET de uma olhadinha [aqui](https://blog.vindi.com.br/como-funciona-o-arquivo-retorno-de-cobranca/).

Basicamente, os arquivos de retorno do bancos **'Não são gerados'**, eles são retornos!

O responsável por fornecer estes dados são os bancos, no seu caso, o [Santander](http://www.santanderempresarial.com.br/) e devem ser extraídos do site do seu banco(o primeiro link demonstra como extrair o arquivo e o segundo um pouco do uso)

Oque sua aplicação deve fazer é: Ler os arquivos retornos do banco.

Com isto é possível saber se os afins foram pagos ou se são inválidos(Seguidos dos códigos que apontam os motivos para isto, para que possam ser devidamente corrigidos)

1. Acesse o [Site do seu banco](http://www.santanderempresarial.com.br/)
2. Clique em Transferência de Arquivo” e depois na opção Retorno, clique em "Consultar".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Caso apareça a tela abaixo, selecione “Transferência Simples” e depois “Personalizar”

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4. Coloque data inicial, data final e depois clique no botão “Enviar”.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

5. Basta Salvar no seu computador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Passo a Passo foi retirado da seguinte [pagina](https://atendimento.vindi.com.br/hc/pt-br/articles/216549968--Santander-Como-extrair-o-arquivo-de-retorno-CNAB-e-importar-para-a-Vindi) e contem 7 passos, porem os últimos 2 podem ser ignorados por serem específicos de um sistema.